# Is Python's os.path.join slow?

Tags: python, performance, string, path

I've been told `os.path.join` is horribly slow in python and I should use string concatenation (`'%s/%s' % (x, y)`) instead. Is there really that big a difference and if so how can I track it?

Comment: Are you familiar with `timeit`?

Comment: That's "string formatting" or "string interpolation". "string concatenation" is `x + '/' + y`

Answer (score 12):

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'import os.path' 'os.path.join("/root", "file")'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit '"/root" + "file"'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0223 usec per loop
```

So yes, it's nearly 50 times slower. 1 microsecond is still *nothing* though, so I really wouldn't factor the difference in. Use `os.path.join`: it's cross-platform, more readable and less bug-prone.

EDIT: Two people have now commented that the `import` explains the difference. This is not true, as `-s` is a setup flag thus the `import` is not factored into the reported runtime. Read [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#command-line-interface).

Comment: I'd imagine that the `import os.path` is the reason why it's 50x slower.

Comment: @Rafe `-s` isn't factored in, afaik. Proof: `$ python -mtimeit -s 'import os.path' ''100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0137 usec per loop`

Comment: 1 microsecond, not nanosecond. It's still not much though.

Comment: @marcog I see, I missed that flag. Regardless, you're right, one nanosecond makes no difference.

Comment: The first expression generates `"/root/file"` here, while the second one generates `"/rootfile"`.  If you want the latter, `os.path.join` isn't going to help you.  If you want the former, note that even this 1-line demo has a bug in it.  :-)

Comment: Comparing import lookup + function call with just one string concatenation operator is completely incorrect.

Comment: @maxp That's correct, but it's not what I'm doing here. Read the comments further up.

Comment: "it's cross-platform, more readable and less bug-prone" amen to that

Comment: @marcog: -1 Concatenation of two string literals is a very bad "straw man" to compare with. Since Python 2.5, concatenation of string literals is optimised away at compile time. Try `python -c "import dis; dis.dis(lambda: 'fu' + 'bar')"` and see for yourself.

Comment: @John Seriously, who cares whether the difference is 5 or 50 times. The conclusion is the same: the difference is meaningless for nearly all purposes and that was the point I was making.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know who told you not to use it, but they're wrong.

1. Even if it were slow, it would never be slow to a program-breaking extent. I've never noticed it being remotely slow.
2. It's key to cross-platform programming. Line separators etc. differ by platform, and `os.path.join` will always join paths correctly regardless of platform.
3. Readability. Everyone knows what `join` is doing. People might have to do a double take for string concatenation for paths.

Answer (score 3):

Also be aware that periods in function calls are known to be slow. Compare:

```
python -mtimeit -s "import os.path;x=range(10)" "os.path.join(x)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.405 usec per loop

python -mtimeit -s "from os.path import join;x=range(10)" "join(x)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.29 usec per loop
```

So that's a slowdown of 40% just by having periods in your function invocation syntax.

Curiously, these two are different speeds:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s "from os.path import sep;join=sep.join;x=map(str,range(10))" "join(x)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.253 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s "from os.path import join;x=map(str,range(10))" "join(x)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.285 usec per loop
```

Comment: I absolutely wasn't aware of this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may be nearly 50 times faster, but unless you're doing it in a CPU bound tight inner loop, the speed difference isn't going to matter at all.  The portability difference on the other hand will make the difference between whether or not your program can be easily ported to a non-Unix platform or not.

So, please use `os.path.join` unless you've profiled and discovered that it really is a major impediment to your program's performance.

Comment: Even if you have profiled and found that `os.path.join` is a performance problem, you should still try to use something like `os.sep.join` or `a + os.sep + b` which would still use the proper separator, and not a hardcoded `'/'`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `os.path.join` simply for portability.

I don't get the point of comparing `os.path.join` (which works for any number or parts, on any platform) with something as trivial as string formatting two paths.

To answer the question in the title, "**Is Python's os.path.join slow?**" you have to at least compare it with a remotely similar function to find out what speed you can expect from a function like this.

As you can see below, compared to a similar function, **there is nothing slow about `os.path.join`**:

```
python -mtimeit -s "x = tuple(map(str, range(10)))" "'/'.join(x)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.26 usec per loop

python -mtimeit -s "from os.path import join;x = tuple(range(10))" "join(x)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.27 usec per loop


python -mtimeit -s "x = tuple(range(3))" "('/%s'*len(x)) % x"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.456 usec per loop

python -mtimeit -s "x = tuple(map(str, range(3)))" "'/'.join(x)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.178 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

In this hot controversy, I dare to propose:

(I know, I know , there is timeit, but I'm not so trained with timeit, and clock() seems to me to be sufficient for the case)

```
import os
from time import clock

separ = os.sep
ospath = os.path
ospathjoin = os.path.join

A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H = [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]
n = 1000

for essays in xrange(100):

    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(n):
        xa = os.path.join('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')
    A.append(clock()-te)


    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(n):
        xb = ospath.join('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')
    B.append(clock()-te)


    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(n):
        xc = ospathjoin('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')
    C.append(clock()-te)


    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(n):
        xd = 'C:\WINNT\system32'+os.sep+'Microsoft\Crypto'+os.sep+'RSA\MachineKeys'
    D.append(clock()-te)


    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(n):
        xe = '%s\\%s\\%s' % ('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')
    E.append(clock()-te)


    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(n):
        xf = 'C:\WINNT\system32'+separ+'Microsoft\Crypto'+separ+'RSA\MachineKeys'
    F.append(clock()-te)


    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(n):
        xg = os.sep.join(('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys'))
    G.append(clock()-te)


    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(n):
        xh = separ.join(('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys'))
    H.append(clock()-te)

print min(A), "os.path.join('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')"
print min(B), "ospath.join('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')"
print min(C), "ospathjoin('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')"
print min(D), "'C:\WINNT\system32'+os.sep+'Microsoft\Crypto'+os.sep+'RSA\MachineKeys'"
print min(E), "'%s\\%s\\%s' % ('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')"
print min(F), "'C:\WINNT\system32'+separ+'Microsoft\Crypto'+separ+'RSA\MachineKeys'"
print min(G), "os.sep.join('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')"
print min(H), "separ.join('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')"
print 'xa==xb==xc==xd==xe==xf==xg==xh==',xa==xb==xc==xd==xe==xf==xg==xh
```

result

0.0284533369465 os.path.join('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')

0.0277652606686 ospath.join('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')

0.0272489939364 ospathjoin('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')

0.00398598145854 'C:\WINNT\system32'+os.sep+'Microsoft\Crypto'+os.sep+'RSA\MachineKeys'

0.00375075603184 '%s\%s\%s' % ('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')

0.00330824168994 'C:\WINNT\system32'+separ+'Microsoft\Crypto'+separ+'RSA\MachineKeys'

0.00292467338726 os.sep.join('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')

0.00261401937956 separ.join('C:\WINNT\system32','Microsoft\Crypto','RSA\MachineKeys')

True

with

separ = os.sep

ospath = os.path

ospathjoin = os.path.join

Answer (score -2):

Everyone sholud know one inevident feature of os.path.join()

```
os.path.join( 'a', 'b' ) == 'a/b'
os.path.join( 'a', '/b' ) == '/b'
```