# Why "os.sep" is faster than "os.path.join()"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I usually use "os.path.join()" when I connect path,I rarely use "os.sep".
But I found "os.sep" is faster than "os.path.join()".Why?

**My test code:**

```
import os
import time

a = 'E:\\video'
b = 'image'
c = '0001.jpg'
start = time.clock()
d = os.path.join(a,b,c)
end = time.clock()
print("%f " % (end - start)) #0.000011
print(d) #E:\video\image\0001.jpg
start = time.clock()
e = a+os.sep+b+os.sep+c
end = time.clock()
print("%f " % (end - start)) #0.000001 
print(e) #E:\video\image\0001.jpg
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: `os.path.join` performs checks on its arguments and modifies them if it has to. `os.sep` is just a separator and you use it to concatenate strings. I find the behavior you are documenting completely anticipated and unsurprising.

Comment: `os.path.join('a', 'b') == os.path.join('a/', 'b')`. Does the performance difference even matter to you, though? A single call to `os.path.join` takes on the order of a microsecond.

Comment: The manual tells you all - if you only read it before questioning here: [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). Maybe you should also study the first few lines of [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - it tells you to do _reasearch_ first, then ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Python's os.path.join slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664306/is-pythons-os-path-join-slow)

Comment: It matters.When I use "cv2.imwrite(os.path.join( image_dst0, '%04d.jpg' % c), bin_image)",there is a difference between different frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can answer this by yourself by [reading the source (windows version)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/ntpath.py#L74) - or even just the doc FWIW:

> Join one or more path components intelligently. The return value is
>   the concatenation of path and any members of *paths with exactly one
>   directory separator (os.sep) following each non-empty part except the
>   last, meaning that the result will only end in a separator if the last
>   part is empty. If a component is an absolute path, all previous
>   components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute
>   path component.
>
> On Windows, the drive letter is not reset when an absolute path
>   component (e.g., r'\foo') is encountered. If a component contains a
>   drive letter, all previous components are thrown away and the drive
>   letter is reset. Note that since there is a current directory for each
>   drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the
>   current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

As you can see, `os.path.join()` does *much* more than mere string concatenation, so yes obviously it's slower.

Answer (score 0):

As per python official documentation for os.path which says :

> Since different operating systems have different path name
>   conventions, there are several versions of this module in the standard
>   library. The os.path module is always the path module suitable for the
>   operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for local
>   paths.

As we can see that it is suitable for os independent path name conventions, there must be additional checks which goes on, for say determining the OS etc, which are the reasons for the time required in os.path.join(a,b,c) call.

Also a+os.sep+b+os.sep+c is just a separator in simple terms which doesn't perform such operations as os.path.